# CXF Corba using Jacorb

Tags: java, cxf, corba, jacorb

I'm trying to use the CXF CORBA binding with Jacorb. I have a bunch of clients and servers that work just fine with Sun's default orb. To use Jacorb, I set the properties

-Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBClass=org.jacorb.orb.ORB
-Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBSingletonClass=org.jacorb.orb.ORBSingleton

(this worked with earlier projects)

With CFX, I get

```
org.apache.cxf.binding.corba.CorbaBindingException: org.omg.CORBA.NO_IMPLEMENT:   vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.corba.CorbaConduit.close(CorbaConduit.java:148)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:541)
...
```

this results from org.omg.CORBA.ContextList create_context_list() in org.jacorb.orb.ORB throwing org.omg.CORBA.NO_IMPLEMENT.

Is this a CXF or a Jacorb issue ? Or am I doing something wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a Jacorb problem.   I don't believe that is an optional method and it should be implemented.

Comment: There's now a branch of Jacorb that sort of works with CXF: ([GitHub](https://github.com/JacORB/JacORB), BZ968). There still some bugs, though [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-5393)

Answer (score 0):

This has now been fixed JacORB trunk. Bug reference: http://www.jacorb.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=968